# unable to install GRUB in dummy

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I am trying dual boot kali linux with windows 8.1 .The linux installation was going smoothly until it reached the step where it needed to install Grub.

[image]

I don't know if it's of any importance but my partitioning scheme was as follows:
/boot was 88GB
swap 8GB
/home ext4 113GB All those partitions are primary.

and I tried other method too like choose disk with most free space but at the end result was same.
I am using hp 215-n15tu with extended 4Gb ram and UEFI mode with ntfs installation and secure boot is off.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a place that you can change `dummy` to other thing.
Change it to the disk your installing, like `/dev/sda`.

Comment: *There should be a place* can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score -1):

This error generally occurs due to improper functionality while writing the USB.
The general reason can be software/application you are using for USB writing. I was using USBwriter, do not use this ever for any type of writing on USB. It makes your USB corrupt(i faced a lot of problem because of this), simply use Win32DiskImager for USB writing.
some people may thought why not rufus, rufus is good though but when your ISO is not EFI bootable it won't let you write for GPT partition scheme for UEFI(eg kali linux) and same is with may other USB writer so try to go for Win32DiskImager.